# heroku procfile problem : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myApp.wsgi'

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

I' m deploying my first django app on heroku. After deploy the heroku doesn't launch my app. After checking heroku `logs --tail`
I have got an error:

```
: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabele.wsgi'
```

My procfile looks like:

```
web: gunicorn tabele.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

I tries also:

```
web: gunicorn tabele:app

web: gunicorn tabele.wsgi --log-file -
```

I'm beginner and I don't understand if (in my case 'tabele') should be folder containing manage.py or the different one?
In my project folders including `manage.py` and another one including  `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` has the same name "tabele"
Could you explain me what is what in procfile file for better understanding?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
djangoherokuapp
  |-- tabele/
    |     |---  __init_-.py
    |     |---  settings.py
    |     |---  urls.py
    |     |---  wsgi.py
    |----- manage.py
    |------Procfile  ⬅⬅⬅
    |------requirements.txt
    |----- app/
    |     |---  admin.py
    |     |---  apps.py
    |     |---  __init__.py
    |     |---  models.py
    |     |---  tests.py
    |     |---  views.py
```

- Add a Procfile in the project root directory to define process types
  and explicitly declare what command should be executed to **start your
  app**.
- Open the Procfile and add the line below:

  `web: gunicorn tabele.wsgi --log-file -`
- `--log-file -` means "log to stdout". The `--log-file` flag lets you
  set a path to a log file, and `-` means "stdout" (in this context).

**Or try with:**

```
 web: gunicorn tabele.wsgi
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Now it works. I put procfile to wrong directory before.